# columns are not aligned with the data in ggplot geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

plotting some data to a figure with numerical data, one would expect the column border to line up with the grid. However, when plotting this data, you can see that there are some that line up correctly (10, 5), but others don't (2, 1).

Is this a bug or a feature?

[image: geom_col columns not aligned with grid]

Reproducible example

```
library(tidyverse, scales)
```

The data

```
x1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
y1 <- c(1, 10, 2, 1, 5)
xy <- data.frame(x1, y1)
```

The plot

```
xy %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(x1, desc(y1)),
             y = y1)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = y1), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white") # to show the numbers
```

## Some experiments

### Correct

```
xy %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(x1, desc(y1)),
             y = y1)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0, 10, .5)) +
  # scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = .5)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = y), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white")
```

[image: correct aligned]

But then

### Incorrect

```
xy %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(x1, desc(y1)),
             y = y1)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0, 10, .5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = .5)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = y), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white")
```

[image: incorrect]

Also incorrect

```
xy %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(x1, desc(y1)),
             y = y1)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0, 10, 1),
                     labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = y1), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white")
```

[image: incorrect also ggplot geom_col]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `2` in yaxis is `2.5` and near `1` is `1.25` not 1.

```
xy %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(x1, desc(y1)),
             y = y1)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = y1), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white")
```

[image]

```
  xy %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(x1, desc(y1)),
               y = y1)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

I don't know why you add `accuracy = 1` but take a look at plot below.

```
xy %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(x1, desc(y1)),
             y = y1)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a rounding error caused by your `scales_y_continuous` call.  Use

```
ggplot(xy,aes(x = fct_reorder(x1, desc(y1)),
           y = y1)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,5,8,10)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = y1), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white")
```

To get what you want.